# Send email to multiple people picker selections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, formula

I have an InfoPath list form that has 2 people picker fields.  I am able to send emails to both fields using this formula below:

concat(substring-after(AccountId, "\"), "@XXX.com", ";", concat(substring-after(AccountId, "\"), "@XXX.com"))

This formula will send an email to the person selected in the first people picker field and to the person selected in the second people picker field.

But when multiple people are selected in the first people picker field (and second people picker field) it only sends it to the first person entered in.  Not the second or third etc.  I know this is a common issue, but WITHOUT using a designer workflow, how can I achieve this?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: If not workflow, then how are you sending the emails?

Comment: With the send email data connection...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **eval** function for people picker in InfoPath.

Reference for you:
[Using eval function for people picker in InfoPath](https://mysharepointpage.wordpress.com/2014/07/14/using-eval-function-for-people-picker-in-infopath/)
[InfoPath email submission and repeating tables](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efadd519-3198-4ac2-b8aa-81dba60127e8/infopath-email-submission-and-repeating-tables?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)